# Angular update UI automatically when ES6 Map's value is changes

Tags: angular, typescript, caching, rxjs, es6-map

I have my full code in below stackblitz link,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-cache-service-with-rxjs-8cywbi?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Here I am trying to update the UI when someone updates the storagelocation(in this case a `Map` - which is in `cache.service.ts` file).

- When I click `Get` method, it get the value from cache and update the UI.
- When I click `Set` method, it update value in a `Map` inside `CacheService`.

Is there any way to update the UI automatically when I call `Set` using RxJs ?

*Note:You can see my new trails in `cache.service2.ts` file.*

Comment: Inside setValue, if you just do this.loadMore$.next(key);it will update your component. Or, make inFlightObservables property in cacheService public and subscribe to that inside your component. Not sure if this is what you meant.

Comment: @jintoppy: this.loadMore$.next(key) will update the UI but with new row. I want to update the existing rows that are already binded in UI. Eg. Assume I clicked "Get 100" once, then one row will be displayed, after that when I click "Set 100", I want to update the 1st row with the new data.

Comment: That you can achieve by adding a check inside scan.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-cache-service-with-rxjs-gm4gxo?file=app/app.component.ts